# Multiple two-class selectors in Sass

Tags: css, sass

Having multiple two-class selectors for a single declaration block, is it possible to simplify the following (i.e. not having to repeat the `body` tag):

```
body.shop, body.contact, body.about, body.faq {background-color:#fff;}
```

Answer (score 128, accepted):

try this:

```
body{
   &.shop, &.contact, &.about, &.faq {
        background-color:#fff;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 29):

In this case we can use `@each` directive:

```
$pages: shop, contact, about, faq;

body {
  @each $page in $pages {
    &.#{$page} {
      background-color:#FFF;
    }
  }
}
```

[sassmeister.com](http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/6fa9490d8738c6fe084be9d62e4fa7d8)

Answer (score 8):

```
body {
    &.shop, &.contact {
        // Styles here...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using sass compiled by the node, that may do.

```css
    body {
      .shop, .contact, .about, .faq {
          background-color:#FFFFFF;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that this directly addresses the question, but with `scss` you can reuse two classes in one like this:

```
.displayFlex {
  display: '-webkit-box';      /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
  display: '-moz-box';         /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
  display: '-ms-flexbox';      /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
  display: '-webkit-flex';     /* NEW - Chrome */
  display: flex;             /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */

}

.flexOne {
  flex: 1; /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
  -webkit-box-flex: 1; /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
  -moz-box-flex: 1; /* OLD - Firefox 19- */
  -webkit-flex: 1; /* Chrome */
  -ms-flex: 1; /* IE 10 */
}

.boxWrapper01 {
  @extend .displayFlex;
  @extend .flexOne;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: beige;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Parent child relationship in sass**

```
parent_tag {
    .child {
       // rules here
    }
}
```